# how can I send and retrieve params in spring?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am triyng to do a simple thing, with ajax, send a request (using a GET, or POST).

I will be sending 2 parameters in a json format , and I just want to get them back and send a response, still, I always get an error 400 and others that I dont know whats wrong, any idea how?

I started based on this article: http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery/

I am using spring mvc.

So far I have this:

```
$(".update_agent").live('click', function(){

            var agent = { "agentId" : agentID, "hostAGent" : hostID};
            //send ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: JSON.stringify(agent),
                type: "GET",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        })
```

and at my java controller I have this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public int updateAgent(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException{
    req.getParameterValues("agentId");
    return AGENT_UPDATE_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I cant get it back, have no idea how to make the request of the params, any idea?

Thanks.

=====================UPDATE============================

Ive changed the code and this how it looks like...

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(agent),
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data) {
           alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
});
```

And at my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Integer  updateAgent(@RequestBody String param) throws IOException{
        System.out.println(param);
        //do something...
        return 1;

    }
```

the problem is that I am getting an error 415, unsupported media type, any advice?

Comment: where did you define Url?

Comment: before the click...same with other constants there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET-request can not have 'data'-field. You need to send your data as part of the url:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url + "?agent=" + JSON.stringify(agent),
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

now you can get the data in your controller as:

```
@ResponseBody public ResponseEntity<String> updateAgent(@RequestParam(value = "agent") String agentJson){
...
}
```

or you can send a POST-request. With a POST-request you can send your data as `requestBody`:

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> updateAgent(@RequestBody String agentJson){
...
}
```

EDIT:
create a new `Agent`-class:

```
public class Agent {
    private long agentId;
    private long hostAgent;
    ...
    getter and setter
    ...
}
```

now update the controller to:

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> updateAgent(@RequestBody Agent agent){
    System.out.println(agent.getAgentId());
}
```

and change the "Content-Type" of ajax-call to "application/json".

EDIT2:
change your ajax-call data to:

```
data: { agentId: agentID, hostAgent : hostAgentID} ,
```

or even

```
data: agent ,
```

**Don't forget to change "hostAGent" to "hostAgent" in your agent object, or you will get 400!!!**

now ajax will send the data as request parameters, you can get the data in your controller by:

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> updateAgent(@RequestParam(value = "agentId") long agentId, @RequestParam(value = "hostAgent") long hostAgentId){
    System.out.println(agentId);
}
```

Comment: when I make a post request I always get a status 415, unsupported media type... any idea?

Comment: just remove `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in your controller

Comment: btw. i would remove `beforeSend` and replace it by header-property: `headers: {
                 Accept : "application/json",         
                "Content-Type": "application/json"   
  }`

Comment: Ive tried that, but I keep getting the same error :s any way to do it without sending as a json? only the 2 parameters?

Comment: this is weird, make sure you remove all accept-header. Make sure there is no another Method with the same request Mapping, but another method. Can you update your ajax-call and controller?

Comment: Hi, thanks, Ive updated the code, could you please take a look?

Comment: what is `@RequestMapping` of your controller?

Comment: hi, is the same, I forgot to include it, Ive updated the edit.

Comment: hmm, try to set `Content-Type` to "text/html" in your ajax-call. I recall, that if you send "json" as `RequestBody` you need a wrapper class, so Spring can parse the data...

Comment: I dont get the error anymore, but the param gets all as string, any idea how to get my params back? the 2 of them?

Comment: yes, it is String now, that you could parse with some library. But try my last update first.

Comment: if I make a RequestBody Agent I get the same error again... is there a way to do it without sending the params on a json format? I dont really mind if is json or not

Comment: just to be sure, in your ajax-call you have "hostAGent", try to change it to "hostAgent" to match the controller implementation. If it still not working, try my last edit